# app crashes when adding OnItemSelectedListener

Tags: java, android

I recently made an update to the iOS version of an app I made and I want to put that same functionality into the Android version. Basically, it takes user input of a year, which they select from a list and then the year previous to that is entered into the placeholder text of text field I specify. When I looked up how to do the same functionality in Android, I found out I needed an OnItemSelectedListener. However, that is when trouble arises. After adding the necessary code, and importing AdapterView into my Activity, my app keeps crashing on first launch. Since I am not sure where it keeps crashing, here is a link to my app's github page

[Github Experimental branch](https://github.com/bryceac/RMD-Calculator/tree/experimental/src/com/MinDis/android)

The code on the master branch works fine, so this is really strange.

Since the files are hard to decipher, here is the code I used to apply the OnItemSelectedListener:

```
// give Spinner a listener for new functionality to work
selection.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, 
                               View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        // get year selection for use with new functionality
        int iyear = Integer.parseInt(selection.getSelectedItem().toString()); 
        balance.setHint(R.string.balance + " from 12/31/" + pyear.getPrevYear(iyear)); 
    }
    // create empty method
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {}
});
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code here along with the LogCat errors. Your link has 9 java files and no hints about where to start looking for the error...

Comment: Easier said than done, concerning relevant code. The Activity is MinDis.java. Everything else is an external class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through and copied things from the master branch and things started working without crashing. Now, I am having issues with the hint, but since this question on why it kept crashing, I am not sure I can keep the question open.

Comment: I also looked through Google's stuff stuff Android and found out I was getting the data the wrong way. This question is definitely closed now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the var balance is not null at the time of setHint. It could be that the id in findViewById is not right.
Make sure that R.id.amount is a view inside of R.layout.main.

Comment: R.id.amount is definitely in the xml layout, even the master branch version, and the ids in the Activity match that found in the xml for the layout.

Comment: The problem is in the editText. You can't mix R.string.balance which is an id ( reference pointing to your string). You need to get that string first as Sam points. getResources().getString(R.string.balance)

Comment: Using `R.string.balance` doesn't create an error, it just creates the wrong String. (For example, "2342912347 from 12/31/2000"...)

Comment: Yep, that's the value of the string. Could you copy the error trace you get back from the logCat?

Comment: Not really. Google page tells me how, but unless I can use grep or something, it goes over my character limit.

Comment: I meant the value of the reference. What do you mean by your character limit?

Comment: You asked if I could copy the error trace from logcat but the output take so many lines and there is a 3000 or so character limit here.

Comment: There are just a pair of important lines to copy here. Normally error that cause crashes appear in red color in the LogCat. Moreover you can filter traces only from your app. Read through the error trace and select the first 3 lines which are related to your code and your classes.

Comment: I don't see any red lines in the logs, unless I run DDMS, which does not even have my application listed, even though I installed it in the emulator via adb.

Comment: I've executed your project and it runs properly and behave as expected. When I run "experimental", the only difference is that there are no years to select. The field of the year activity shows just the header (no year to choose). But it runs again properly.
I've tried in 4.0 and 2.2.

Comment: That's weird. I wonder why it crashes for me then. I'll try running it in 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't see the LogCat which is the **most** vital piece of information when tracking down an error...

So these are my guesses:

- I don't see where you define an adapter for `selection` so I assume that you do this in the XML. Have you confirmed that `selection.getSelectedItem().toString()` is a valid String for `Integer.parseInt()`?

  If you have access to the array (call it `selectionArray`) you can simply use:

  ```
  ... + pyear.getPrevYear(selectionArray[position]);
  ```
- `R.string.balance` is an integer that references the String that you want. To display the String itself you want to use `getString(R.string.balance)` or probably `getResources().getString(R.string.balance)`.
- Verify none of your variables are null: `selection`, `balance`, and `pyear`.

---

To explain the first point a little more:

1. Create a class variable for the array and the String:

   ```
   int[] choicesArray;
   ```
2. Initialize it in onCreate();

   ```
   choicesArray = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.choices_array);
   ```
3. In OnItemSelectedListener use:

   ```
   balance.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.balance) + " from 12/31/" + (choicesArray[position] - 1));
   ```

Comment: last part of balance.setHint looks redundant because pyear, since it creates an object of the prevYear class, does that subtraction already, but I'm trying your hint.